# Android XML drawable transparent gradient

Tags: android, xml, gradient, drawable, transparent

I would like some clarification on what the code in front of the HTML color code is called and how it functions.

1) I'm assuming, in the example below, the `endColor` of `#00000000` with the two preceding `00` tells the color to be generated more transparent than say `FF`.

2) But what's the scale?

3) Is there some kind of hex scale that equates to certain percentages?

I'm really confused and can find no documentation because I'm not even sure of the the terminology I should be searching for other than 'xml transparent gradient' which doesn't tell me what I want to know.

Any/All help is appreciated. Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#DD63594A"
        android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:angle="90"/>
    <padding android:left="4dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="4dp" 
        android:bottom="1dp" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="1dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="1dp" 
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's hexadecimal. The scale is the same as the RGB values in the rest of the color code, so `00` would be `alpha=0` and `FF` would be `alpha=255`. Basic math explains the rest.

Comment: Thanks! Very concise explanation and easy to understand now.

Comment: rgba should be renamed to argb for various reasons, foremost to reduce the number of questions like these on SO.  I also like the 'arg' factor.

Answer (score 0):

```
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00
```